# Warning when using a component from a variable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `AppBar` from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar and am facing some issues.

My code looks like this:

```
const Menuright = (props) => (
    <IconMenu
        {...props}
        iconButtonElement={
            <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
        }
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    >
        <MenuItem primaryText="Edit Profile" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Upload Sample" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
    </IconMenu>
);

Menuright.muiName = 'IconMenu';

function coloredHeader(type, props=null) {
    const className = "App-header App-header-" + type;
    const styles = {};
    switch (type) {
        case 'main':
            styles['backgroundColor'] = notLoggedInColor;
            break;
        case 'artist':
            styles['backgroundColor'] = artistColor;
            break;
        case 'organizer':
            styles['backgroundColor'] = organizerColor;
            break;
        default:
            styles['backgroundColor'] = notLoggedInColor;
    }
    const titlestyle = {
        cursor: 'pointer'
    };

    return <AppBar className={className}
                   title="Legato"
                   style={styles}
                   onTitleTouchTap={ontaptitle}
                   titleStyle={titlestyle}
                   iconElementRight={Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? <Menuright/>: null}>
    </AppBar>;
}
```

which is very close to the provided samplecode.
This generally works but gives me some warnings:

```
index.js:2177 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check your code at CommonStyle.js:75.
```

I get this warning three times.

The line causing the warning is

```
iconElementRight={Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? <Menuright/>: null}>
```

If do not use the `Menuright` variable but instead inline the IconMenu code, it will not produce the warning.

Could anybody explain to me why this warning is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your problem has something to do with the way you are importing/exporting the components. Could you post how you are doing that? Furthermore, coloredHeader is supposed to be a component? If so, why is the first parameter not props?

Comment: Please share how you are rendering `coloredHeader` component.

Comment: are you using named exports?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it works by using `IconMenu` instead of `Menuright`?

Anyway, that error message is likely that component is trying on the inside to do something like:

```
const Component = props.iconElementRight

return <Component />
```

And `Component` instead of being the function that builds that component, is already an instance of that component, because you pass `<Menuright/>` instead of just `Menuright`. Like this:

```
iconElementRight={Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? Menuright : null}>
```